# How to detect if a PDF page has an image in it

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working with PDF/A style PDF documents that have a mixture of scanned in, full page size images and then a page or two after the image pages that have text in a ColumnText object.

Using Java, how do i detect which pages have an image?

The intent to detect which pages have either images or text is to determine where the first page with text appears. I need to either edit the text or replace the page(s) with text with updated text. The pages with images would remain untouched.

I'm using iText5 and don't currently have the option of upgrading to iText7.

Here's the solution I implemented with the solution provided by @mkl:

ImageDetector.java

```
package org.test.pdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;

public class ImageDetector implements RenderListener {
    public void beginTextBlock() { }
    public void endTextBlock() { }
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        textFound = true;
    }

    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        imageFound = true;
    }

    boolean textFound = false;
    boolean imageFound = false;
}
```

PdfDocumentServiceTest.java

```
package org.test.pdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
import com.test.PdfService;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@ActiveProfiles({"local", "testing"})
@DirtiesContext
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PdfDocumentServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private PdfService pdfService;

    @Test
    public void testFindImagesInPdf(Long pdfId)) {
        final byte[] resource = PdfService.getPdf(pdfId);
        int imagePageCount = 0;
        int textPageCount = 0;
        if (resource != null && resource.length > 0) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
            PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++) {

                ImageDetector imageDetector = new ImageDetector();
                parser.processContent(pageNumber, imageDetector);

                if (imageDetector.imageFound) {
                    imagePageCount++;
                }
                if (imageDetector.textFound) {
                    textPageCount++;
                }
            }
            Assert.assertTrue(imagePageCount > 0);
            Assert.assertTrue(textPageCount > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you should use some kind of library (for example, Apache PDFBox) to parse and analyze the PDF documents, because PDF is a rather complex document format.

Comment: The simplest way to find pages with images is to traverse the page tree and see if a page's resource dictionary contains an image object. However, this is not foolproof: a page may also indirectly reference images via nested objects. So you would also have to recursively look into the page's XObjects, Shadings, and Patterns. And to be really sure, you would have to check that these objects are actually referenced in a content stream -- just because the document contains an image, doesn't mean it's actually visible if you open the document in a PDF reader.

Comment: @AndreasMayer, I'll work on adding an example of what I've worked on so far. I am using PdfReader.

Comment: `PdfReader` sounds like a class name, not a library name. I know at least two different pdf libraries with a class of that name. Please clarify.

Comment: @mkl, I am using iText5 ( com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader ).

Comment: *"how do i detect which pages have an image"* - by "have an image" do you mean "have images in their page resources" (used or unused) or do you mean "show images when displayed"? At first glance [Dheeraj Malik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53368048/1729265) looks for the first type.

Comment: @mlk: Full-page-size images were scanned from paper documents and generated as PDF. Later additions to the file may have been made using iText, adding the text to a new page in a ColumnText object. I'm needing to find the images to determine where the first page of text occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using iText 5 you can find out whether images actually are shown on a page by parsing the page content into a custom `RenderListener` implementation. E.g.

```java
class ImageDetector implements RenderListener {
    public void beginTextBlock() { }
    public void endTextBlock() { }
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        imageFound = true;
    }

    boolean imageFound = false;
}
```

used like this:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++)
{
    ImageDetector imageDetector = new ImageDetector();
    parser.processContent(pageNumber, imageDetector);
    if (imageDetector.imageFound) {
        // There is at least one image rendered on page i
        // Thus, handle it as an image page
    } else {
        // There is no image rendered on page i
        // Thus, handle it as a no-image page
    }
}
```

As a possible improvement: In a comment you mention *full-page-size images*. Thus, in the `ImageDetector` method `renderImage` you might want to check the image size before setting `imageFound` to `true`. Via the `ImageRenderInfo` parameter you can retrieve both information on how large the image is displayed on the page and how large it actually is.

Comment: This worked great!! I'll add my code to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code example ([Spire.PDF for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/pdf-for-java.html) library is needed), hopefully it works for you.

```
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    doc.loadFromFile("sample.pdf");

    for(int i = 0; i < doc.getPages().getCount(); i ++) {
        PdfPageBase page = doc.getPages().get(i);
        PdfImageInfo[] imageInfo = page.getImagesInfo();

        if (imageInfo != null && imageInfo.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("Page" + i + "contains image");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print("Page" + i + "doesn't contain image");
        }
```

**Disclaimer:** I work for Spire.

Comment: Does `page.getImagesInfo()` represent the images in the page resources (both used and unused) or the images actually used on the page (inline, from the page resources, or from xobject resources shown on the page)? As an aside, `doc.getPages().indexOf(page)` is merely a complicated way to write `i`, isn't it?

Comment: @mkl page.getImagesInfo() represents all of the images in the page. Sorry I made a stupid mistake :(, just updated the answer, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: *"all of the images in the page"* - in the page as PDF object (i.e. in the page resources), in the page as display unit (i.e. all images used to render the page), or a combination thereof?