# detect images in multiple pdf files

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, image

I have a large set of PDF files (10,000+). They have multiple pages in the pdf files (can be anywhere from 1-25 or more). Some pages have images (and some only text). I want to detect if a certain page has an image. So for example, the images are on page 5, 12, 15. PDF is OCR'd (searchable)

Then output these results to an excel file for analysis (since there are so many pdf files).

is this possible using python or java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324326/how-to-detect-if-a-pdf-page-has-an-image-in-it Check if above link helps

Comment: @Vishruth, I saw that. unfortunately it doesn't answer on how to handle multiple PDF files and to export the results to an excel file for analysis. im having issues on how to bring it all together. thanks